# My web application dont load styles files when in production

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

[My project](https://github.com/alex-martins2305/ToDo4) in Django works very fine in production, bootstrap, css, everything loads perfect.
But in deploy to render.com the css file doesn't load.

I already checked:

- In github the files are available in static/css/styles.css;
- run collectstatic;
- cleaned browser data;
- tried in Mozilla  and Chrome (desktop and mobile);
  In chrome I can see in inspection/network the reason to not apply the style file: Refused to apply style from [link](https://todo4-hk3r.onrender.com/static/ccs/styles.css) because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: Django does not serve any static files. Therefore the problem lays within the config of the "dealer" of your static files. Usually this "dealer" is nginx or apache. What do you use?